# Not able to deploy my website on google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I have made a website which is working on localhost.
But I am unable to deploy it on the server with google app engine. I don't use Eclipse. In google app Engine there is a tab for deploy on top. But when I press that deploy nothing happens. 
When I go to the webpage of the server it shows server not found. 
I also tried to deploy with command line argument

```
appcfg.py -A simplegraph-007 update app.yaml
```

But it just one the appcfg.py file and my website is not deployed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: `But It just one the appcfg.py file and my website is not deployed.`? Did you [install the SDK for your platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)? What platform is that? What errors are you getting when running the command you provided?

Comment: Sorry Mistake. It just open the appcfg.py file and when I check my site it is error 404. No error while running the code everything is good. But Deployment doesn't happen. I use appengine 1.19.27 (python). It is running on local host but not able to deploy it. Hope to hear from you thanks,

Comment: Assuming (1) you're doing this on a Windows machine & (2) your Python installation path is `C:\Python27` you would have to run the following command in the directory of your app.yaml: `C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py" update app.yaml`. If any of the paths do not match the ones on your system - you'd need to adjust them accordingly.

Comment: What does The following line **you would have to run the following command in the directory of your app.yaml: C:\Python27\python.exe **  means? I didnot got it. I have run app.yaml using python

Comment: 1. Open cmd.exe 2. Within cmd.exe navigate to the directory where your app and the app.yaml file is. 3. Now that you are in that directory - enter the following `C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py" update app.yaml` and hit enter (assuming the paths I listed are correct but if they're not - simply adjust them accordingly).

Comment: It is showing me error in Running. Import google inputoutput error: No module name Google.  It is showing me while running appcfg.py.   Thanks for your help. Can You help again .Thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling this error you're getting now? I already asked you earlier - have you installed the SDK from the provided link?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked for me. Thankss